# How to remove categories filter from wordpress admin?

Tags: categories, admin, customization

I removed the categories column from "All posts" page by applying this code.

```
add_filter("manage_edit-post_columns", "my_post_edit_columns");
function my_post_edit_columns($columns){
  unset($columns['categories']);
  return $columns;
}
```

This code removed categories column. But still i see the categories filter in the top.
Is there a way to remove it other than using CSS to hide it?

Thanks

Comment: That's because there is no relation between the categories column and the filter. You should look for another hook/filter with which you can remove the filter on top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this and it works for removing the categories dropdown on the All Posts page:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'no_category_dropdown' );
function no_category_dropdown() {
    add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', '__return_false' );
}
```

-- below: old answer when I misunderstood the question --

The code you posted works just fine for me. But here's an alternative you might try:

```
add_filter("manage_posts_columns", "my_post_edit_columns" );
function my_post_edit_columns($columns){
    unset($columns['categories']);
    return $columns;
}
```

This *will* also impact other post types that have a 'categories' column.

Comment: It's not about the column, but the filter on top of the table (as written in the question).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I was thinking of the screen options checkbox.

Comment: Yep. I want to remove that categories filter. I searched for hooks [in this site](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/) but couldn't find anything. :(

Comment: Edited my answer and added new code now that I understand the question. Sorry for my confusion! :)

Comment: Awesome Kailey, It works... :) Is it possible to apply code for "date" and "bulk actions" filter too?. I don't want them too if user logged in as subscriber

Comment: Remove bulk action with: 

`add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . 'edit-post', '__return_empty_array' );`

Not sure about date, I'm looking though.

Comment: @KaileyLampert Once you found the date filter, please update your answer. It will be useful to many people and you will gain more reputation. I've searched it in many sites, some site give solution but its based on CSS. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any way to remove the date filter using hooks. Seems like CSS is the only way to go presently.

Comment: Ok then, i'll either apply css or keep date filter as it is. Bye.TC

Answer (score 1):

I think the select elements are passed through the `wp_dropdown_cats` filter.  So you should be able to add a filter to that which returns a blank string.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code? I'll try it

Comment: add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'remove_dropdown_cats' ); function remove_dropdown_cats(){ return ''; } edit: go with Kailey's code, attatching it all to the load-edit.php action is a good idea.

Comment: Is it possible to apply code for "date" and "bulk actions" filter too?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_cats', '__return_false');
```

Here is the original [wp_dropdown_cats](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_cats/) function, this filter will return default post categories

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: If this is just a filter for the dropdown's HTML I'd expect you'd want return empty string not false?