# Unregistered taxonomy apears still as emtpy filter list

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pages, taxonomy, dropdown

I [unregistered](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type/) a custom taxonomy form the theme I'm using:

```
function wpse314876_unregister_taxonomy() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'page_category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse314876_unregister_taxonomy' );
```

But in the all pages overview (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`) it shows still an empty drop-down filter list. *I can [remove all category drop-down](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37634) but that's not what I want as I already [added a custom drop-down taxonomy filter-list](http://thestizmedia.com/custom-post-type-filter-admin-custom-taxonomy/).*

The drop-down appears as a little empty list [image: empty list] and its HTML looks like that:

```html
<select name="page_category" id="page_category" class="postform">
</select>
```

---

How can I remove just what empty drop-down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I little digging I found the right action in the parent theme. The function looked like that (actually exactly the example I [linked](http://thestizmedia.com/custom-post-type-filter-admin-custom-taxonomy/) above):

```
//////////////////////////////
// Add page category filter //
//////////////////////////////

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'uncode_page_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy');

function uncode_page_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy() {
    global $typenow;
    $post_type = 'page'; // change to your post type
    $taxonomy  = 'page_category'; // change to your taxonomy
    if ($typenow == $post_type) {
        $selected      = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
        $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' => sprintf(esc_html__("Show All %s", 'uncode'), $info_taxonomy->label),
            'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
            'name'            => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'         => 'name',
            'selected'        => $selected,
            'show_count'      => true,
            'hide_empty'      => true,
        ));
    };
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'uncode_page_convert_id_to_term_in_query');
function uncode_page_convert_id_to_term_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $post_type = 'page'; // change to your post type
    $taxonomy  = 'page_category'; // change to your taxonomy
    $q_vars    = &$query->query_vars;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($q_vars['post_type']) && $q_vars['post_type'] == $post_type && isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0 ) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
        $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution

To remove them I added a simple [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to my child-theme `function.php`.

```
/**
 * Remove page_category filter and parse query
 *
 **/
remove_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'uncode_page_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy');
remove_action('parse_query', 'uncode_page_convert_id_to_term_in_query');
```